# UV Unwrap Order Of Operations (Cloth Sim)

Tags: animation, uv, physics

I am making a shirt for a character I have made, and I want to get a UV unwrap so I can properly apply textures and such after it is made. I am going to be using a cloth simulation to get the shirt to drape on the body properly. I have already created the base mesh for the shirt, and marked out seams for where I want the UVs to unwrap. My question is this: Do I need to do the UV unwrap BEFORE doing the cloth sim and baking it in, AFTERWARDS, or does it not matter? Thanks in advance for any help with this topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the end result should theoretically be the same, you should probably unwrap the base mesh prior to running the simulation.

It will be much easier to get a clean UV map with a proper layout from a plain undeformed base mesh then from a wrinkled and highly subdivided result of the physics simulation.

However, unless you apply the result of the simulation, you can always sweep the timeline backwards at any time, and return to a point before the first frame of the simulation, where the mesh is still intact.

So you can theoretically still UV Map a mesh if you already ran a simulation, as long as you can still revert to the base mesh shape.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's all the answer I needed to proceed with my project.

Comment: Don't just thank in the comments, this site works best if you up vote when an answer helped you, and if it solved your problem consider marking it as accepted so it can help others in the future.

Comment: I did upvote your answer, but because I am beneath a certain level of rep, my upvote doesn't show. It told me that it DID log my upvote in the system though. Just noticed the "accept" button; will do that part now.